# Does Google cap impressions of my website?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

It looks like my site hit an imaginary limit of 400 daily impressions.

What is this limit based on? How can I "break through" that limit?

[image]

Comment: It's really odd that you had *exactly* 400 impressions four days in a row and hit it six times in 12 days.

Comment: I have always thought that this is only a graphics display thing. For example, in the past when 300 was the highest number ever achieved, then the graphic would cap at that, its not a limit to the impressions themselves. every time you get to a higher number, the graphic caps at that. That's what has always happened to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's webmaster tools shows this data with only one or two significant figures.  Because of this, graphs often exhibit this type of appearance.  You also commonly get graphs that look like stair steps.

Here is a list of values you are likely to see on your chart (but never numbers in between):

```
<10 12 16 22 30 35 50 60 70 90 110 150 170 200 250 320 400 500 600 700 900 1,000 1,300 1,600 2,000 2,500 3,500 4,500 5,500 6,500 8,000 12,000 15,000 22,000 27,000 40,000 50,000 60,000 75,000 90,000 110,000 140,000 170,000 250,000
```

When it says that you got 400 impressions, it means that you got around 400 impressions.  It could actually be 360 to 450 impressions or 400 to 500 impressions, depending on how they do their rounding.   Four days in a row that got impressions in that range wouldn't be uncommon.

Here is a screenshot from my graph that shows something similar

[image]

I believe that Google does this so that they can store this data very efficiently.  Because they don't have much accuracy, they may only use 8 bits to represent all positive integers.

**EDIT:** [Google is announcing that this graph will no longer be rounded and bucketed](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/01/search-queries-not-rounded.html) like this.  In the future it will be more accurate.

Comment: cool, I did not know that. is there a source?

Comment: Once you get enough impressions you start seeing lots of zeros.    I might see 2,200,000 impressions or 1,800,000 impressions, but never anything in between.